# GLSL gl_PrimitiveID always 0

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I am trying to output gl_PrimitiveID as a color in a fragment shader. However it's always equal to 0.

Here is my fragment shader:

```
void main(void)
{
    if(gl_PrimitiveID == 0)
        gl_FragColor.rgba = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1); // red for 0
    else
        gl_FragColor.rgba = vec4(0, 0, 1, 1); // blue otherwise
}
```

and vertex shader

```
void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = ftransform();
}
```

The output color for triangles is always red.
I am drawing the triangles with glDrawElements and the render is ok when using the default shaders.

What am i doing wrong?

Here is how I draw the triangles:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexPosBuffer);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, NULL);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexNormalBuffer);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, NULL);

glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
glEnableClientState( GL_NORMAL_ARRAY );

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementBuffer);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, countVertices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)0);
```

Comment: Where are your other shader stages? Particularly geometry, if you have one.

Comment: For something to reach the fragment shader it *has* to be passed through in the other shaders. also any compile link errors in your shaders?

Comment: @Andon I added my vertex shader to the original post. I don't have any geometry shader.

Comment: @ratchetfreak if no geometry shader is present, `gl_PrimitiveID` is filled by the implementation.

Comment: @ratchetfreak No compile nor link error. I don't understand.  [This documentation](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Fragment_Shader/Defined_Inputs) says that gl_PrimitiveID is the index of the current primitive being rendered by [this](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Rendering). I assumed glDrawElements was part of the set. But I am wrong or missing a gl call.

Answer (score 3):

After hours of banging my head against the wall, I realized my vertex shader was not attached to the right program id.

Only the fragment shader was attached. It seems gl_PrimitiveID does not auto increment if the vertex shader is not provided.

+1 to Andon and ratchet for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: I don't know why you were downvoted.  Even though I have a lot of experience with OpenGL, it's easy to overlook something.  In any case, I upvoted you because I found what you were trying to accomplish very useful.  I used the `gl_PrimitiveID`global to reference an aligned array of ints for altering shader behavior per-poly.  Saved me a lot of trudging through docs :-)